# Reactive Java Webflux request being terminated after 60 secs

Tags: java, nginx, spring-webflux

I am new to the Reactive Java stuff, in our application we are using Reactive Java with webflux for the restapi. 
One of our api is taking more than a minute to respond, and after 60 seconds am seeing the 504 gateway timeout in postman. But, I can see that the process(under the API) is being terminated abruptly with the following message. I want my api to continue with processing even after request timing out after 60 secs. Not sure how to do that in reactive java.
Also am running the app with docker image with nginx in it.

```
**Process terminating abruptly with following message**
reactor.Flux.FlowableAs.1 -
               | cancel()


**504 gateway timeout response.**
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>504 Gateway Time-out</title>
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="white">
            <center>
                <h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
            </center>
            <hr>
            <center>nginx</center>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing the webapp without nginx in between? We have seen similar issues and they were caused by the intermediate proxy.

Comment: when I access without nginx its not timing out but it times out only when i access through nginx

Comment: Then it is most likely something related to the nginx configuration, you should update the question accordingly.

Comment: I want to know why process stops after nginx time out. I expect java process to continue even after nginx times out.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the Nginx reverse proxy is closing the connection to the WebFlux application.

This closing event is forwarded up the reactive chain as a `cancel` event, meaning the processing of the request is being cancelled from the bottom up. This is actually a pretty neat feature since it gives the chance to the application to stop processing things and cleaning up resources properly.